# The obstacle is not on my cost map

Tags: navigation, ros2, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I give a goal for the robot, it will bump into the obstacle.
I am using Humble and NAV2.

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

> global_costmap: global_costmap:

> ros__parameters: update_frequency: 2.0

> publish_frequency: 2.0 global_frame:

> map robot_base_frame: base_link

> use_sim_time: True robot_radius: 0.1

> resolution: 0.05 track_unknown_space:

> true plugins: [“static_layer”, “obstacle_layer”, “inflation_layer”]

> static_layer: enabled: True plugin: “nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer”

> map_subscribe_transient_local: True

> obstacle_layer: plugin: “nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer”

> enabled: True

> observation_sources:

> scan scan: topic: /scan

> sensor_frame: “base_scan”

> max_obstacle_height: 2.0

> clearing: True marking: True

> data_type: “LaserScan”

> expected_update_rate: 1.0

> raytrace_max_range: 3.0

> raytrace_min_range: 0.0

> obstacle_max_range: 2.5

> obstacle_min_range: 0.0

> inflation_layer: plugin: “nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer”

> cost_scaling_factor: 1.0

> inflation_radius: 0.55

> always_send_full_costmap: True

> global_costmap_client:

> ros__parameters:

> use_sim_time: True

> global_costmap_rclcpp_node:

> ros__parameters:

> use_sim_time: True

**local_costmap:**

> local_costmap:

> ros__parameters: update_frequency: 5.0

> publish_frequency: 5.0
> global_frame: odom

> robot_base_frame: base_link

> use_sim_time: True

> rolling_window: true

> width: 3

> height: 3

> resolution: 0.05

> robot_radius: 0.1

> always_send_full_costmap: True

> plugins: [“obstacle_layer”, “inflation_layer”]

> obstacle_layer:

> plugin:

> “nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer”

> enabled: True

> observation_sources: scan

> scan: topic: /scan

> max_obstacle_height: 2.0

> clearing: True

> marking: True

> data_type: “LaserScan”

> expected_update_rate: 1.0

> inflation_layer:

> plugin: “nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer”

> cost_scaling_factor: 3.0

> inflation_radius: 1.0

> always_send_full_costmap: True

> local_costmap_client:

> ros__parameters:

> use_sim_time: True

> local_costmap_rclcpp_node:

> ros__parameters: use_sim_time: True

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402555/the-obstacle-is-not-on-my-cost-map./) by [BlueBird](https://answers.ros.org/users/98868/bluebird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2022-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is indeed a real issue chronicled here: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/issues/3014

The summary of the issue is that Humble/Rolling in 22.04 moved from Cyclone DDS to Fast-DDS which is causing failures in the message filters required to process incoming data. We have a temporary patch in PR https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/3018 but we're working on getting some assistance at the Fast-DDS/client library level to resolve the issue which we found with Fast-DDS which many projects may be impacted by.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BlueBird](https://answers.ros.org/users/98868/bluebird/) on 2022-06-21**:
I used the temporary patch, and it seems to work.
[it seems to work](https://i.postimg.cc/0jRgCjq4/i-Shot-2022-06-21-22-17-53.png)